# python Scrapy: how to control the items in output json file?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using python scrapy for a project in which I will get items continuously. 
I want to output items to a set of .json files and make sure that each of them
contains a fixed number of items, say 1000. I know scrapy provides a way to 
output as json:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html

But it seems not included a method to generate multiple json files
to store items automatically as mentioned above.

I wonder if anyone has encountered similar problem or has similar need?
How to tackle this problem if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: count them as you serialize them and then when you get to your fixed count open, write and close a file and start over

Comment: I'd do this on the pipeline level. Define class-level variable that would keep the count of exported items. Then, in the `process_item` method close the exporter file and open another one if the count achieved the limit. See an [example code](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters) from docs.

Comment: Can you please explain on how to Define this class-level variable which can be accessed in pipeline? @alecxe